# R: How can we choose minimum in rows of a matrix when there are many minimums?

Tags: r, matrix

suppose I have a 3*4 matrix as below:

M=[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.01

0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02

46, 45, 45, 48]

To find the frequency of minimum and to find which column has more minimums in M, I use:

table(apply(M,1,which.min))

but since there are two equal minimums in each row, the function just counts the first column as a minimum.

Now, I'm trying to have a function that computes the equality in minimums for all of the matrix and say for example in 30% of cases (each row is a case) the columns 1 and 3 are minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You can return all the column numbers which are minimum in a row as one string and use `table` to count the frequency.

```
cnt <- table(apply(M,1,function(x) paste0(which(x == min(x)), collapse = '-')))
```

To calculate the ratio you can `sort` the counts and calculate proportions.

```
prop.table(sort(cnt)) * 100
```